# How to figure out why os stalled

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, crash

I'm guesing it was either a disconnected ssd running the os, or the power supply unit , an uniterruptible power supply that is old. Because i was moving the ssd around within the desktop at the time, but it never got disconnected from the sata connector, and was also moving the power supply unit (which is older and also has battery that wasnt 100 percent secured in place). how to figure out which it was?

I checked journalctl and there was a 20 minute gap , and the last remaining message was a totally normal systemd journal for a process i was running. I checked the journalctl --boot=-1 to see the messages before i had to manually reboot it. It had none from 20 minutes prior to reboot (thats when it stalled)

At the point it stalled, ssh wasnt working any more, and monitor (connected with vga cable) was producing no output, but fan was running. Would a watchdog timer be able to reboot, automaticaly for this scenario. IT couldnt be a total power loss either because computer bios is cofigured to auto restart in case of power going off and back on. Maybe a power output fluctuation problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you have a bad power supply where the capacitor(s) are starting to go bad. I've seen that before with a server, it would start the boot process and then everything seemed to hang. Nothing in the logs that I could see.

Troubleshoot everything and then used a power supply tester and saw that one of the SATA cables on a cold boot for the power supply didn't have the right wattage. We ended up replacing the power supply after assuming one of the capacitors was going bad.

If you don't have a power supply tester, I would turn off the computer, unplug it, press the power button a few times to remove any power from the capacitors, and then plug it back in and see what happens.